# How to have a part of the decorated text - NOT decorated?

Tags: css, html, text-decorations

How can I make the span inside the decorated paragraph, not decorated?

CSS

```
p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* text-decoration: line-through; */
}
```

Further away I'd like to put a line through the undecorated span.
I have a feeling like this should be very easy to do, hence I couldn't find a solution online, or it might just not be logical to do, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using the approach you suggest, it may be possible if you could style the text nodes *inside* the paragraph, but CSS doesn't have a selector for text nodes.

You can certainly achieve the desired result, but it will require styling sibling elements rather than a parent element. For instance you could wrap the other text inside `<span>` elements and style those instead.

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="underline">Is</span>
  <span class="line-through">this</span>
  <span class="underline">what you want to do?</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by a simple trick which is give a text-dectoration:underline for the span and change its color to be the same background-color

like in this snippet

```
p{
  font-size:25px;
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline; 
 }
p span{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:underline;
  text-decoration-color:#fff;
}
```

see the result in this pen https://codepen.io/norhanms/pen/mgYoJr?editors=1100